# Trouble connecting via paramiko + kerberos

Tags: python-2.7, ssh, kerberos, paramiko, gssapi

Currently when I want to connect to a node I simply do: `ssh username@node` and everything works fine. (thanks Kerberos :-))
Now I'm *trying* to develop a simple python script that connect to a specified host but I cannot connect to it using that script.
The following my script:

```
import paramiko
import gssapi

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect(hostname = 'node_name', username = 'my_uname', gss_auth = True, gss_kex = True)
```

But I received this error:

```
paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.
```

I tried also

```
ssh.connect(hostname = 'node_name', username = 'my_uname', gss_auth = True, gss_kex = True, gss_deleg_creds=True)
```

and the error I received changed a bit:

```
gssapi.error.GSSException: (131072) An invalid name was supplied. Minor code: (100001) Success. Target: node_name
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you find the answer. Since i am trying run the connect from local, do i need to install pywin32 instead gssapi ?